# Como escrever essa query usando linq lambda em c#

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

A query que eu tenho q passar pra lamba é a seguinte:

```
select * from Linguagem inner join Cadastro on Lin_ID=Cad_IDLinguagem and Cad_Situation=0
```

só coonsegui fazer até a parte da junção mas o where não sei em que parte entra:

```
return odb.Linguagem.Join(odb.Cadastro, l => l.Lin_ID, c => c.Cad_IDLinguagem, (l, c) => l).ToList();
```

Desde já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Ola, tente algo assim:

```
odb.Linguagem.Join(odb.Cadastro,
                     l => l.Lin_ID, 
                     c => c.Cad_IDLinguagem,
                     (l, c) => l)
             .Where(x => x.PROPRIEDADE == VERIFICAÇÃO)
         ).ToList();
```